# UITableView Cell style subtitle should display text on the right side

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I used subtitle style as my Cell style in UITableView, but I need my `detailTextLabel` to display the detail on the right side of the cell. By default the subtitle appears on the left. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at either UITableViewCellStyleValue1 or UITableViewCellStyleValue2.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon Paul's answer a little, when you are initializing your table view cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath you need to do something like this.

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```